# Why doesn't a device with x509/PKCS#11 and U2F exist?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, u2f, fido

I've been looking for a device, smartcard or USB that does two things:

- provide storage to a private digital signature key (used with in a standard x509 certificate) for signing documents
- provide U2F credentials for authentication with web applications.
- optional: NFC or a way to use it from mobile device

I've found only one vague reference that a yubikey could do both (but it's not fips140-2 certified). Why are the other players in the field not developing devices with both functionalities? Gemalto, nitrokey, etc.

Is there some fundamental incompatibility with "old" PKI smartcards and U2F ? Both do similar operations at their core.

Answer (score 4):

The [Yubikey Neo](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/compare-yubikeys/) can do all three things you need.
The standard Yubikey (non NFC) is, according to the website, in the process of beeing FIPS 140-2 certified.

An overview of certified U2F tokens can be found on the fidoalliance [website](https://fidoalliance.org/fido-certified-showcase/?swoof=1&product_cat=security-key-nfc,usb-security-key&pa_specification=u2f)

Generally speaking, U2F is a rather new standard, and the mainstream crypto token producers like Gemalto or SafeNet haven't quite jumped on that train yet. Technically, there is nothing that prevents a token from living in the PKCS#11 and U2F world at the same time.

Comment: Correct. Im using the Yubikey 4 with Smart Card (PIV) With PKCS11 interface and the U2F features.